# Reading Specific Byte data From File

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have an 8mb file which contains some records.
I want to read a particular record from a particular place.
I have the starting and ending byte index of every record in the file.

My problem is how to use a file dialog box to select the particular file and make a function that reads the file and then stores a particular record in the textbox.

I also have a doubt on how to read all the records at one time in all the textboxes.

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions before you ask any question here

Comment: first try some thing, later ask the question here......

Comment: but i am beginner programer in vb.net. if i selected file but how to use that file name in function of read byte to read the records

Comment: Use the file dialog to determine where the file is located you which to read in the stream.  You have to at least post what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

First,I need an index of my file values suppose ***product id =id09876543** location =india* then **index values of id09876543 is " 12 to 23 "**
then i will pass 12 and 23 in function calling.

1. make a user define function called "read_value" pass the 2 argument in it in integer form and make function as string i.e. it will return value in string format.
2. call that function in your specific place where you want the answer.

like this.

1)

Public Function read_value(ByVal strat As Integer, ByVal end1 As Integer) As String

```
    Dim fs As FileStream = New FileStream(f_name, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)

    Dim n As Integer = 0
    Dim s As String = Nothing
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    Dim l As Long = strat
    fs.Seek(l, SeekOrigin.Begin)
    'Seek(strat)
    For i = strat To end1
        n = fs.ReadByte()
        s = s + Convert.ToChar(n)
    Next
    Return s
End Function
```

2. 

Dim ofd1 As New OpenFileDialog
' Dim file_name As String
Try
If ofd1.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
f_name = ofd1.FileName

```
            product_id_txt.Text = read_value(12, 23)
            location_txt.Text = read_value(34, 50)
            form.Show()
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("File Not Found")
    End Try
```

Output of this code is
label----->Product Id: id09876543  <---- this is my text box value